# Can an inanimate thing lift Mjolnir?

Tags: marvel, mjolnir

Can an **inanimate** thing can lift Mjolnir without the help of a living being (unworthy)

**Scenario 1**

Mjolnir in a very light car with a sail attached to it, then a very strong wind blew and moved the car uphill.

It is possible or not?

**Scenario 2**

Can upward wind alone lift the Mjolnir?

Comment: Well, great question.. Because worthiness isn't defined for wind etc.

Comment: By _non-living things_ are you only referring to elements of nature? From the title I was expecting a question about the undead...

Comment: @Daft going to edit my question about that

Comment: _inanimate things_? The answer is probably yes. The earth is inanimate, it rotates. If Thor put Mjolnir on the ground, the earth wouldn't stop rotating.

Comment: Here, hope this helps somebody already answered this.

http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/87086/44844

Comment: The elevator is not worthy. But can lift the hammer. We've even seen Thor hang the hammer on a ... coat hanger (Dark World)

Comment: Asking if an inanimate object can lift the hammer is like asking if a computer thinks or a submarine swims. It doesn't make sense. Inanimate objects don't lift the hammer (like an elevator) so the magic doesn't apply and also the elevator doesn't get  Thor's power.

Answer (score 11):

#### Andy, the Mad Thinker's Amazing Android emulated Thor's worthiness and was able to lift Mjolnir.

[image]

- But if you were asking could Mjolnir be in a plane and the plane still fly? Yes. On a ship and the ship still move? Yes. Thor's hammer was on the helicarrier, in his stateroom and the ship left the water and flew through the air.
- If Mjolnir was in a car on a hill could the car still roll down the hill? Yes. Mjolnir seems as affected by natural forces like gravity as anything else. We have seen the hammer move through the air but any force strong enough to move Mjolnir around would certainly be too dangerous for most mortals to be in.

Comment: Although, as a counterpoint, Stan Lee pulls the transmission out of his truck, trying to use it to pull out Mjolnir. He might have failed due to human intent to move the hammer, or perhaps that it was "grounded" in some way because no own currently owned it.

Comment: Could Thor's presence on the helicarrier have enabled it to move Mjolnir by proxy? I.e. Thor doesn't need to be directly holding Mjolnir for the carrier to move Mjolnir as Thor intends it, just as he can call Mjolnir to him from anywhere.

I imagine he'd be able to pin down a robotic enemy or a tank using Mjolnir just as Loki was pinned down by it when Thor willed it.

Comment: Which comic did this occur in? And do you know the issue?

Comment: Nest question: If you can manipulate gravity, then could you move Mjolnir?

Answer (score 6):

At the Age of Ultron we see Tony, Steve and Thor discussing:

> How The Vision is able to lift Mjolnir.

They seem to imply there might be rules for non-living thing as 'a lift can move mjolnir'.

Comment: I got the impression that Vision could lift it because be was worthy, being a very pure AI derived intelligence.

Comment: @mojo what do you mean by 'very pure AI'?

Comment: Vision was originally the Jarvis AI.

Comment: But why does that make him 'very pure '?

Comment: He was a formless AI. No body, no wants or desires or malice.

Comment: Vision seemed to have a "soul" and an intent to do "right" which perhaps made him worthy.

Answer (score 3):

Even without magic, the uru metal that Mjolnir is forged from is hardly weightless.  It is one of the densest, strongest metals in the Marvel Universe.  So, that must be taken into account with talk of sails and floating.

Robots and other nonliving automatons can move Mjolnir.  Following are three comic images that I had easily on tap.  I can think of other moments, but don't have the citation evidence readily on hand.

Journey into Mystery #86 shows a robot making grab.

The Mighty Thor #210 shows magnetic (part mystical?) force "lifting" the hammer.

The Mighty Thor #355.  Discusses nonliving creatures doing the heavy lifting.

[image: Journey into Mystery #86]
[image: Thor #210]
[image: Thor #355]