# What makes this character worthy to lift Thor's hammer, Mjolnir?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron, magical-items

After being created and brought to life by a stroke of Thor's lightning

> Vision casually passes Thor his hammer without even straining.

I think there was a gasp from the cinema audience at this point, I'm quite confident this was not in the comics.

Why is this character deemed worthy to lift Mjolnir?

I see three possible reasons:

1. > The mind stone, an infinity gem, overpowers/overrides Odin's enchantment
2. > Thors lightning imparts some of his worthiness
3. > Vision is considered worthy by Odin

Which is it it, or is it another option?

Comment: The Hammer's enchantment maybe sees Vision as the equivalent of a baby? How can you judge a newborns worthiness?

Comment: Is it possible that the hammer doesn't register Vision as a sentient being, because he's an Android?

Comment: @Dennis_E: So any given Iron Man armor should be capable of lifting the hammer as long as it's controlled by Jarvis instead of Tony? I doubt that...

Comment: I'd think its closer to ash_k29's comment Vision can probably move the hammer because it brought into its current state of being by a lightning stroke from the hammer, making it more of an extension of the hammer. Which would allow vision to get by the worthiness requirement.

Comment: Because Vision is a pure virgin. Unlike the rest of the Avengers.

Comment: @PrajeetSingh What's the canon source for both this assertion, and for the implication that being a virgin (which Thor, having IIRC wife and kids isn't) is either necessary OR sufficient to be worthy to lift it?

Comment: After watching the movie one thing I am pretty certain about is my interpretation that even Thor trusts that Vision is worthy.

Comment: everyone is missing one major point. The Vision can alter mass. We never see The vision wield the hammers powers, we only see him move it. And manipulating mass is his forte. Just something to chew on.

Comment: @WIllJBD Vision certainly wields the hammer at the end in The Church.

Comment: @apnorton I don't remember seeing him "wield" the hammer. I only remember him picking it up and tossing it to Thor. Perhaps he hammered a bad guy or two with it. I don't remember him using it to fly, cause a tornado, shoot lighting, or anything else that could not be explained mass manipulation. I am not saying he isn't worthy to wield the powers of Thor, and I am not saying that he is. I don't know, I do know the he can manipulate mass and I remember seeing nothing to prove he actually could wield the powers of the hammer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

#### SPOILERS - In small print on the side of Mjolnir - "Worthiness lifting requirements may be waived in the event of a sentient machine operator. No powers included."

**UPDATE:**

**[Whedon On Avengers: Age Of Ultron Moment Where Thor Trusts The Vision](http://comicbook.com/2015/05/05/whedon-on-avengers-age-of-ultron-moment-where-thor-trusts-the-vi/)**

- Joss Whedon reveals in an interview/podcast he used the Vision lifting Mjolnir as a "narrative shorthand" to say the Vision was a "good guy."

> "That came from a 'Do you know what would be cool?' moment. It’s the
> cheer moment of the film. And what’s great is that, like the Hawkeye
> thing, we’d set it up – we’d unknowingly set it up, just by having
> that ['Who is worthy enough to Mjolnir?'] sequence, then with
> Quicksilver as well, trying to grab it and it throws him off. Both of
> those things were in the script before I came up with the idea of [the
> Vision lifting Mjolnir].
>
> I had done something similar in an episode of Angel, where I needed
> you to know someone was telling the truth. It was, very simply, Angel
> saying, 'He hates it if you ask questions, he can’t lie.' So, you just
> accept that.
>
> So on the one hand, I want them all to trust each other and go into
> battle not as a coherent group, but when they finally all show up at
> the church, they really do come together for the first time.
>
> On the other hand, I need them to take this guy with them, and I need
> something to say, 'All right, we’re off!' And that really does answer
> a lot of questions. It was so much fun and so cute. Chris added the
> 'Nice work!' as he walked by Tony, by the way."

- This clarifies my position that the Vision is not "worthy." Vision doesn't get any of the powers of Mjolnir, he just lifts it. **Whedon needed a way to make the Avengers trust the Vision and move the movie along.**
- This flies in the face of the previous expressions of worthiness (in the comics) and instead takes the hammer into a nebulous region of being used as a mystical polygraph.

> **[The Vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vision_%28Marvel_Comics%29) is an android, a sentient machine.**. There has already been precedent in the Marvel Universe for androids, who are NOT alive, to be able to pick up Thor's hammer. **See: [Awesome Android](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/86991/2765).** This loophole does not allow them to wield any of its powers, however, since the hammer essentially does not register them at all. **Picking up Mjolnir and wielding its powers are two different things!**

- Adding to this, the Destroyer picks up and holds on to Mjolnir when Jane Foster's Thor engages it in battle. Since the Destroyer is a weapon inhabited by a spirit, the Destroyer can lift Mjolnir, but gains no powers. With its already superhuman strength, Mjolnir makes a great club.

[image]

- If you can lift it, and swing it, then technically you are wielding it but not gaining the power of THOR, just using his hammer like an oversized croquet mallet. If Vision had summoned a lightning bolt with it, threw it and it returned to HIM, then I would have said, he was WORTHY because he would exercising the powers of THOR and not just playing polo with Ultron...
- Recently, Thor's grandfather Bor has also either overpowered or simply ignored Mjolnir's worthiness requirement.

[image]

> - This immovability enchantment has been subverted as well. Mjolnir has been wielded by a select number of other individuals: alien Beta Ray Bill; Avenger Captain America; Eric Masterson; Odin (Thor's father); Borr (Thor's grandfather); and Buri (also known as Tiwaz, Thor's great-grandfather).

[image]

> - The hammer has also been lifted by various sentient constructs i.e. Galactus' herald, **[Air-Walker](http://marvel.com/universe/Air-Walker_%28Gabriel_Lan%29)** (animated by the soul of Nova Corps captain Gabriel Lan); and **[the Awesome Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awesome_Android)** (by mimicking Thor's abilities and worthy nature). The hammer has also been lifted by Earth itself when animated via magical means. --Wikipedia -> Mjolnir (comics)

[image]

- When Mjolnir is dropped or set aside, it takes a fixed position, from which it cannot be moved except by a 'worthy' individual. This power does not stop the hammer from being driven from place to place in a vehicle unless Thor does not want it to be moved. If it is dropped by Thor in a battle, its "default" setting is immovable until summoned by Thor. So while on the Helicarrier, Mjolnir could sit on a shelf somewhere until Thor called for it and it would still be immovable to a person trying to drag it away, but perfectly able to be flown where it needs to be.

**The verification of qualification of worthiness with Mjolnir is simple. If you can't summon a storm, throw lightning, or use Mjolnir to fly, you are likely a machine just moving Mjolnir from one place to another and trying to look cool doing it.**

[image]

Yes, when you have the power of Thor, you look something like this. So, she clearly qualifies.

Comment: This does make sense. But one thing for sure, the fact implies more towards Vision being worthy rather than him being inanimate as witnessed in the movie. That is why Thor is willing to leave behind such a huge responsibility & privilege in Vision when he leaves for Asgard.

Comment: According to your answer, Ultron could have lifted Mjolnir (powers not included) without effort? Let's say Thor is not around to prevent Ultron from doing so.

Comment: Perhaps. Since the producers did not show this, perhaps the like the idea of keeping the parameters of worthiness vague. We don't see the Vision USING Mjolnir, just lifting it. Historically, we never see Ultron lifting or trying to grab Mjolnir. We are never told why except perhaps he might know he can't, or he may have decided it would offer too little to his already considerable capabilities. I can remember no comic attempts by Ultron to lift the hammer, off the top of my head.

Comment: From memory, The Vision does hit Ultron with Mjolnir, in the ruined church, while Thor is... providing a wordy distraction.

Comment: Exactly - you could lift Mjolnir with a forklift, even a tiny remote control toy forklift, because the issue isn't weight, but what is doing the lifting.

Comment: So basically like mentioned in the movie, Vision is as worthy as an elevator

Comment: I'm not sure Thor's paternal ancestors being able to use the hammer counts as subverting it's powers... after all, he would have received it from them.  It was probably Odin's while Borr ruled Asgard, for example.

Comment: No. Thor's hammer was MADE for Thor, as the mythology goes. It is a subversion because they have the magical pussiance to overcome Odin's enchantment by brute force. Their powers are the equal (and before Odin stole the some of their powers for himself) they were more powerful.

Comment: I have to disagree @Thaddeus - not only does Thor imply that The Vision is worthy at the end, but also your first point is negated by the fact that Mjolnir was at rest when The Vision picked it up. They specifically made the "woompf" sound when Thor set it down, indicating it should stay there.

Comment: Being able to be moved by androids and the like makes much more sense as to why the helicarrier was able to lift it in Avengers 1. That always bothered me, but now I know!

Comment: The Whedon quote clinches it, even if [Omegacron's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/87025/3804) is more concise and to the point.

Comment: "This clarifies my position that the Vision is not "worthy." Vision doesn't get any of the powers of Mjolnir, he just lifts it. Whedon needed a way to make the Avengers trust the Vision and move the movie along." This point doesn't make a lot of sense. It only works as a scene to make the Avengers trust Vision because **they** take his lifting of Mjolnir as proof that Vision passes the worthiness test. You could argue that the Avengers are all mistaken, but nothing about that is in the scene, or your quote from Whedon.

Answer (score 25):

**We don't know, but we can speculate**. Based on the context, the most likely explanation is that

> The Vision is completely pure of character, having recently been born with no opportunity yet to become corrupted or un-worthy. Like a newborn baby, at no point in his life has he experienced anger, deceit, selfishness, or any other "un-worthy" emotion. Unlike a child, however, he has an understanding of right and wrong, and has chosen to help The Avengers defend the innocent - perhaps even to the point of sacrificing himself.

Then again, we still don't have a complete understanding of [what makes someone worthy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4404/20557). However, this theory is supported by dialogue in the film - in fact, it's the dialogue immediately preceding the event in question:

> **CAPTAIN AMERICA:** Are you? On our side?
>
> **VISION:** It's not that simple. (pause) I'm on the side of life. Ultron
>   is not.

This seems to indicate that The Vision does not see the struggle as "Avengers vs. Ultron", but rather as "Life vs. Death" - the purest of conflicts, with no room for moral ambiguity or variables. As such, his motive is equally as pure - to protect life.

The second prevailing theory - and one that *may* be supported by dialogue in the movie - is that The Vision can pick up Mjolnir due to his nature as an android. This is implied by Steve and Tony near the end of the movie, with the following dialogue:

> **THOR:** He can lift the hammer, he can keep the Mind Stone. It will be
>   safe with him.
>
> **TONY:** Well, he's not a man, after all. He's an android.
>
> **STEVE:**  What about an elevator? If you put the hammer in an
>   elevator...
>
> **TONY:** ... it still goes up.
>
> **THOR:** Ah (laughs) I will miss our talks.

On the other hand, that first line by Thor would seem to support the first theory. Thor seems to imply that The Vision is a worthy protector of the gem because of his character... not because of his nature as an android. As it is, we are left to guess.

Comment: I cannot agree with this... being "pure" or "benevolent" is not the same as worthy. I thing that to be worthy one has to earn it by deeds, so no newborn would be able to do that...

Comment: @Bardo you could be right. The problem is that A) we don't know what exactly constitutes being "worthy" and B) it's never been consistent in the comics.

Comment: @Omegacron - There is no such dialog. They do not have any discussion(at-least not a serious one) regarding this.

Comment: @ash_k29 ah ok, thanks for clearing that up. Someone else had said that Tony implied something about a "non-machine warranty" or something afterwards. Sucks being 2 weeks behind everyone else.

Comment: @Omegacron - Can totally understand your pain bro.. Tony & Steve do discuss this in the end, not very seriously though.... & End up with an explanation that involves an analogy of Thor's hammer being in an elevator & the elevator carrying it upwards... (No wonder Thor doesn't stay here full time :D )

Comment: Now that I've actually had a chance to see the movie for myself (twice), I've updated the answer accordingly. For the record, I still think I'm right.

Comment: In the italian version of the movie TONY says "unworthy elevator" :D

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps Vision is just THAT purehearted. Captain America managed to budge it slightly, and Vision seems a lot more chill, accepting, and considerate. He even regrets having to destroy Ultron despite his obvious amorality and genocidal tendencies, where nobody else really does. He's kind of a really zen all-loving paragon from what I could tell.

Comment: I like this. I feel that this is exactly what makes Vision worthy.

Comment: Except that Thor, who definitely *is* worthy, is definitely *not* "chill" or "zen".

Comment: I like the idea that Captian America didn't pick up the hammer on purpose.

Answer (score 3):

The actual quote/enchantment is *Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor.*

> We see Vision holding and wielding the hammer, but he never actually uses any of Thor's powers (lightning etc.)

This led me to believe that he isn't considered *worthy* to use it.

Besides, it isn't Thor who decides who is worthy (as shown from the first movie. He thought he was worthy, but couldn't lift it until he showed he was worthy), so the Hammer itself decides.

The rest of the other explanations give good enough reason for why he can *lift* it though, and I will summarize the possible reasons below.

One explanation:

> In the final scenes, when Thor, Tony and Steve are discussing how Mjolnir works (but it can go up in an elevator!) I think it could be a similar thing happening. The Vision isn't really a person being considered worthy, he is an android. He can simply move the hammer around, like it is being moved in an elevator.

Another explanation:

> Whether the Hammer understood that it was its own powers that allowed the creation of Vision, or something resonated between it and the Infinity Stone, he may be allowed to lift it without actually using its powers.

Comment: Vision probably doesn't use the hammer's ability to call down lightning because he isn't aware of it. And he can already fly, so he doesn't need to use it for that, either. That's really about it for the Hammer's magic, except for the whole "worthiness" enchantment. Thor can't call down lightning without the hammer, so it isn't really a "power of Thor", so to speak, but a power of the Hammer wielded through Thor, its legendary wielder.

Answer (score 1):

> Vision is worthy (in the eyes of Odin's enchantment).

Proof from the movie:

> The original plan was taking the yellow mind stone to Asgard, but in the end Thor himself said that Vision was worthy so he could let him keep the Infinity Stone. This proves the point.

and

> A side note: Thor's lightning just provided power to the system. A moment ago, Quicksilver unplugged power cables from the system.

Comment: I’m not quite clear what your answer actually is. You’re saying Vision is worthy because Thor thinks he is?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Nope. Odin's enchantment thinks that he is worthy.

Comment: Sure, but you said “The original plan was taking the yellow mind stone to Asgard, but in the end Thor himself said that Vision was worthy so he could let him keep the Infinity Stone. This proves the point.” How does *that* prove that Odin’s enchantment thinks the Vision is worthy?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It's obvious. What/who else can decide that in real-time?

Comment: I didn’t ask whether it was obvious, I asked how Thor’s statement proves that the enchantment thinks he’s worthy. But ignoring that, the question is asking *why* Odin’s enchantment deems the Vision worthy. I don’t think you’ve answered that.

Comment: This argument is "The Vision is worthy, because Odin/Mjolnir deems him worthy, because he picked up the hammer, because... he is worthy". You're not actually saying anything.

Answer (score -2):

Overall I would say that it's a matter of character and honor. Thor became worthy when he was willing to sacrifice himself for his friends and the humans. So like Christ, once he died and came back, he was then worthy of those great powers, or in Christ's sake, to become eventual King of the world and universe at His second coming.

This attitude is also why Captain America was also able to wield Mjolnor and I believe that I read somewhere that Superman was also the only other person worthy and honorable enough to be able to wield the hammer.

Comment: I do not see why this answer is given negative votes. Even on Marvel Wiki it clearly says that Captain America IS worthy to lift Thors hammer. As a matter of common sense, it's always been understood that only those with no lust for power, that fight for truth, justice and righteousness without seeking reward, fame, fortune or power are those considered most worthy. This is true in countless religions including many stories of those that attained great heights, only to abuse their positions for self seeking and glory and lose it all. Captain America is not like that at all making him "worthy"