# Can Iron Man's armor in Sentry mode, or Iron Legion, hold Mjolnir?

Tags: marvel

If Iron Man isn't inside his suit of armor, and is allowing his AI to control it, or if Iron Man is using his AI-controlled extra suits and bots, can the armors/bots then lift and wield Mjolnir?

I know robots have done so in the past. And as mentioned in a movie, an elevator could probably lift it. So, is Tony's indirect control over his automatons enough to disqualify them as machines by the magic of Mjolnir?

An answer for any Marvel universe is fine.

Note, in [Can an inanimate thing lift Mjolnir?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86985/can-an-inanimate-thing-lift-mjolnir) it's implied inanimate objects *can* lift it, but it's some of the more well-known examples found in Wikis. I'm wondering if someone has specific knowledge not necessarily cataloged yet.

Comment: Regardless if it could lift it, it wouldn't be able to use it as anything other than a average mallet of the same weight. Re: Magneto lifting it with magnetism, and the one guy who became the same material as mjolnir in the EMH cartoon

Comment: @cde That'd be fine by me. It could be used to sequester or retrieve the hammer from/for the rightful user.

Comment: If his AI was controlling the armor, would it not count as the AI lifting it?  Subject to judgement by whatever rules of worthiness that allow or disallow anyone else?

Comment: @Megha But they aren't controlled by true AI, that's why Tony wanted to build Ultron. They're more like sophisticated... Elevators.

Answer (score -3):

I still believe that Mjolnir is a technology that decides itself who can wield it and who can't so I would think that no matter what, unless it wanted Tony Stark to wield it, it won't let him or anyone lift it.