# Can Iron Man's robots (or JARVIS) lift Mjolnir?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, mjolnir

My friends want to know if Iron Man's suit can lift Mjolnir, or any of Iron Man's "robots" or JARVIS can do the same. They cite when JARVIS controls Iron Man suits in the 2nd and 3rd Iron Man movie. I am looking for a canonical answer, so I don't care if it is from the movies or comics.

Comment: "Canonical answer" is pretty meaningless term in comics since Marvel has a whole multiverse for how it works in different media. In one universe, it might be possible, in another universe, it might not. Now if you were just referring to a certain universe, you might be able to get a "canonical" answer.

Comment: There's a scene in the 1st Thor movie where Stan Lee is trying to move the hammer with a truck and it won't move. However, at the end of 'Age of Ultron', Cap and Iron Man joke about an elevator being able to move the hammer. It seems the enchantment on the hammer somehow knows whether or not an intelligent being is trying to move it, even indirectly.

Comment: Your “friends” want to know — mmm, sure. Bro it’s cool to be a geek now. Let your freak flag fly right alongside ours.

Comment: This one time, at Mjolnir camp...

Comment: @PaulD.Waite _I'm_ a Freak :)

Answer (score 14):

## Marvel Cinematic Universe (Earth-199999)

Iron Man tries to use his suit to help lift Mjolnir, but is unable to.

It's unclear whether or not JARVIS operating the suit could lift Mjolnir. However, since Vision had part of JARVIS in him, it's possible that JARVIS alone might have been able to lift it, should he too demonstrate worthiness.

## Ultimates Universe (Earth-1610)

In Ultimatum #5 and in Ultimates 3 #5, Magneto was able to use his powers of magnetism to control Mjolnir. It follows that Iron Man could devise a robot or suit that lifted the hammer through magnetism as well.

[image]
[image]

## Mainstream Universe (Earth-616)

[Magneto can't lift Mjolnir](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/17193/13217) in this universe, so magnetism is out of the question. However, Iron Man, with the help of his suit, is able to lift Thor's hammer…in space!

[image: Iron Man Lifts Thor's Hammer in space]

Iron Man says that nobody but Thor can lift the hammer on Earth, which would include himself. Presumably that's with the help of his suit.

Also, Andy, the Mad Thinker's Amazing Android [has emulated Thor's worthiness and could pick up Mjolnir](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/86991/13217). Presumably if one of Tony's other robots could do the same, they too could lift Mjolnir.

[image]

Comment: "What about the rest of us?" "Go away" *Tosses them into a fissure*. Damn, Magneto...

Answer (score 5):

The inscription reads, "Whosoever holds his hammer, be he worthy, shall posses the power of Thor."

"WHOSOEVER" not "WHATSOEVER"

There was a scene that Thor hangs his hammer on a coat rack. How can a coat rack be able to carry the weight of Mjölnir? I guess that is because the coat hanger is not alive.

In the movie, Tony puts on his gauntlet to try to lift it, I mean he was in the suit, thereby Mjölnir won't budge.

What will happen if Thor puts Mjölnir in an elevator? Will it be able to carry it up? I guess it will. Elevator is a machine.

Jarvis is an AI, a machine, so I believe Jarvis controlling an Iron Suit would be able to pick up the hammer. "Pick up" not "wield it".....It will only be a normal hammer, It won't possess the power of Thor.

Comment: Coat rack is not worthy

Comment: Addendum: The hammer was placed at rest on the Helicarrier in The Avengers, and this did not cause the craft to immediately plummet.

Answer (score 2):

Unlikely.

In *Age of Ultron*, Tony puts on the gauntlet from one of his Iron Man suits, and is unable to lift the hammer. He can't even do it when Rhodey adds one of his suit's gauntlets to the mix. This implies that the suits themselves aren't "worthy" -- it would require someone worthy to be wearing it.

Vision appears to be a special case -- he's not merely a robot in a suit, he's a fusion of Stark robot, JARVIS AI, and Mind Stone magic. Somehow, collectively, that makes him able to lift Mjolnir.

Comment: But that was Tony with a gauntlet, the question is about robots without a person in them.

Answer (score 2):

In the Age of Ultron, Tony Stark and James Rhodes both had gloves on from the different armors and still weren't able to lift the hammer. Thor's hammer has the enchantment no being can lift it unless they’re worthy of it, just like when the Hulk tried to lift it aboard the Helicarrier if Jarvis was controlling amp Iron Man or War Machine armor, he would be able to lift the hammer but he would not have the power of Thor.

Answer (score -1):

The suits can no doubt not lift Thor's hammer, as you see when Tony and Rhodey attempt to using parts of two separate suits. Jarvis is also incapable, as he is only artificial intelligence, and has no physical form.

Answer (score -1):

Any thing that is being "willed" to lift the hammer has to be worthy

Vision WAS WORTHY the mind stone was merging PARTS OF several consciousnesses, Jarvis, Ultron, Stark, and Banner all held together by the Mind stone. Within a Synthetic body. Collectively they form Vision a Synthetic being WITH THE UPMOST LOVE FOR LIFE HERE IS ONE THEORY..

The Theory that The MCU version of Vision is actually Adam Warlock. In the comics Warlock wears the stone in his forehead...and there is only one stone of that kind..

In the comics warlock (a Synthetic lifeform) was chosen as the champion of life. BECAUSE OF HIS LOVE FOR LIFE. 
Vision also has a love for life. He states in the movie ("I am on the side of life" when asked whose side he was on (Ultron's or Mankind's)

Therefore he is capable of the ultimate GOOD.  Whatever is necessary to protect life.

He is therefore capable of lifting Thor's Hammer.

---

Now regarding the coat hook supporting the hammer.. The answer to that is actually pretty simple.

Here it is......dun dun dunnnnn!!! Thor told it to stay there....so it did...

---