# Is Vision really worthy?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

Inspired by [this question (Can Iron Man's robots (or JARVIS) lift Mjolnir?)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123459/can-iron-mans-robots-or-jarvis-lift-mjolnir/123463#123463), it occurs to me that if inanimate machinery (e.g. elevators) can lift Mjolnir, is Vision really proving himself "worthy" by doing so in Age of Ultron?

Vision is a synthetic, an Android, with an AI. I suppose this depends on what constitutes a "who" vs a "what" in the MCU, but still.

Is there evidence to suggest that as an artificial construct, not motivated by any human will, Vision would not be able to lift Mjolnir even if he weren't "worthy"?  Isn't he just a hyper advanced elevator with some extra features?

Comment: So is your question essentially: "Is Vision actually worthy or is it because he's not a 'person' that he can lift it irrespective of his worthiness?"

Comment: Shield were unable to move it using various lifting equipment in Thor. Of course, that's not quite the same thing - they were operated by unworthy humans after all. But if the operator is what makes the difference then that still suggests Vision is more than a simple machine and that his worth factors into the equation, right? I mean, I imagine if Tony was somehow able to hack Vision and tried to force him to lift Mjolnir, it would likely fail, otherwise that's a huge loophole - bad guys could just create a worthy robot and then have it controlled by a villain.

Comment: Thor isn’t motivated by any “human” will either, you big space racist.

Comment: @Paul, do you mean a *spacist*?

Comment: Elevators cannot lift Mjolnir. They many take it up but they're not actually "lifting" it off the floor.

Comment: given that tony and steve have this exact debate with thor and don't come to a conclusion, I suspect the movie left this intentionally unanswered.

Comment: Given that the Iron Legion referenced in the original question were controlled by an AI (JARVIS), I don't see how this question isnt a dupe.

Comment: @Edlothiad: no no, that’s someone who’s racist against space itself.

Comment: Aren't you just a hyper-advanced slime mold with some bells and whistles?

Comment: @delinear: "bad guys could just create a worthy robot and then have it controlled by a villain" -- that actually happened. Specifically, the Awesome Android (AKA Awesome Andy) created by the Mad Thinker could copycat anyone's powers -- specifically Thor's, and yes, when he did he was worthy to lift Mjolnir, [as discussed here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/79403/60000). (Fortunately the experience was also the catalyst in emancipating him from villainy, as he did it by copying Thor's *worthiness* specifically.)

Answer (score 2):

Let's take it as read that Vison satisfies the requirements of sentient being. That rather simplifies the question. It's his own motivation that drive the desire to move the hammer, as opposed to someone operating him remotely.

Magic Spells are notoriously fickle. There have been endless discussion of the definition of the word "worthy", and whether or not it can change based on the situation. There's an argument that the spell, or perhaps the hammer itself, can "decide" if a person is worthy.

Beta Ray Bill picked up the hammer and received the power of Thor. His cause was just, his desire to good sincere, so he was deemed worthy.

The SHIELD agents trying to move the hammer were not deemed worthy; whether they moved it by hand or with machinery is largely moot.

Captain America budges the hammer by just a millimeter or so earlier in the film, far more than the rest of the crew.  So while Cap himself is certainly as pure of heart and "worthy" as any person, at that moment he was trying to lift the hammer as a goof, perhaps even as an act of pride.  So the hammer "decided" that the need was not worthy, and stayed put after the slightest moment of introspection, which allowed for the nudge. I know he's lifted the hammer in the comics (citation needed), and if, in the heat of battle, he needed it to same lives, or even just to throw it to Thor, there's every chance he could, at that moment.

At the moment of his creation, he has no hubris, no pride, and is only interested in doing good.  He is not trying to use the hammer himself, only to hand it to its proper owner. Indeed, he's not even aware of any restriction about picking it up, so there's not even the chance of doubt creeping into his mind - "Can I do this? Am I worthy?". Looking at that moment, with that mindset, it's very likely that the hammer/spell would decide worthy = true. If he tried it again after the battle, he may not be able to, as the moment of need had passed.

Comment: `Let's take it as read that Vison satisfies the requirements of sentient being.`: The whole question is essentially is Vision sentient or AI and you just dismiss that and then ramble on about something else.